# How can we delete specific rows from HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We have a huge number of text files containing information about clients. We have to delete specific rows from this HDFS file; for example rows associated with the clients X, Y and Z and keeping the others.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a hive table on the top of that hdfs location , then create another one from first hive table with filter logic.Now delete the first hive table.Make sure that tables should be internal.

Comment: While it works, the overhead of creating a Hive schema seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a "row" only makes sense for line-delimited data. For example, if you had Parquet data, or XML files... You want to delete *records*.

One does not simply "delete records" from HDFS files. [HDFS is an append only filesystem](https://www.quora.com/Is-HDFS-an-append-only-file-system-Then-how-do-people-modify-the-files-stored-on-HDFS).

If the data is already on HDFS, the best you can do is read the files, filter out data you don't want (using whatever tool you want - Pig or Spark would be the easiest IMO), then write a new file, optionally overwriting the old data.

To prevent this from happening, you need an ETL process between the data source and HDFS which sanitizes the data ahead of time.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that we have not the right to keep this informations.. So we have to find a solution for deleting them..

Comment: Like I said, this is the best you can do. Even if you are using Hbase or Hive, it is still rewriting the HDFS file

Comment: If you don't have the right to store them. I assume it's PII data, so you should put a process *in front of* HDFS, which prevents that data from ever being written at all.

Comment: @cricket_007 I can understand what problem Youssef is facing -- it is not as simple as preventing writing such data at all. Sometimes it's perfectly valid and legal to store such data as the subjects (e.g. users) have permitted it to be stored for valid processing. But then say users delete their accounts, and so at that stage PII data of such users need to be removed from system. Not storing PII data at all is not a solution -- some PII data is absolutely required to provide service. Big data systems need to evolve to handle this sort of efficient deletion.